# Alternatives to twist-off

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm watching SOA and a guy who says "*oh, it's a **twist-off***", referring to the bottle cap that is supposed to be twisted off the bottleneck, rather than being leveraged by a bottle opener.

Then I've realized that I don't know the name of the alternative(s). What'd he say if he'd be expecting a *twist-off* but discovered that the opposite was the case? Are there several alternatives in this case?

And grammatically prone to nitpickiness makes me wonder if it's correct to spell the term hyphenated, "*twist-off*" or unhyphenated "*twist off*". Perhaps both are correct?

Comment: General Reference. [screw cap](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/screw+cap) *- a cap that screws onto the threaded mouth of a container such as a bottle or jar.*

Comment: ...if you're grammatically *prone to **nitpickiness*** you might like to note that ***What'd** he say if...* is a very unusual contraction for *what **would** he say*, even in speech. In writing, it doesn't look at all natural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers According to my English teacher, "*what'd*" is to be used freely as a contraction of both "*what would*" and "*what had*" (and mustn't be confused with "*what did*", of course). That always baffled me (the *would/had* duality), so I'm reading your comment with great satisfaction. Is that localized and different in US and UK? Or is that a general English?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also, recognizing your deep competence in English (sucking-up intended to its fullest), would you care to offer an answer to my question? I'm still stuck on that...

Comment: I must admit I've never been sure whether [Roy Orbison's *What'd I Say*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qsqs_cbDntA) was short for *what **would*** or *what **did***. But if you type just the first word into Google with "instant" turned on, ***all*** the suggested autocompletes are references to that song. So far as I'm concerned, it almost never occurs in any other context. As to the matter of using a hyphen or space (or just making it a single word), there's no "authority" on it. But I will say such things "tend to trend" towards the single-word form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe the question is asking "*[screw cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_cap_(wine))* is to *[cork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_(plug))* as *[twist-off](http://m5.paperblog.com/i/71/713084/starr-hill-moving-away-from-twist-off-bottle--L-5K1PUy.png)* is to what?"

Comment: @choster: oic. Yes, I suppose it's true some people reserve *screw-cap* for wine bottles, and only use *twist-off* for beer bottle caps that just need a quarter-turn to remove. The correspondence is *screw-cap/cork* and *twist-off/crown cap*, as WS2 says (except that I personally have always called them [crown **corks**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=crown+corks&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=1eLJUuqdH8va0QWiwICQDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQsAQ&biw=1404&bih=864), bizarre as that might seem).

Comment: At the ground level, every one (other than English language enthusiasts) seem to be just saying *non-twist-off (beer)* -- why complicate and be non-understood? https://www.google.com/#q=%22+non+twist+off%22

Comment: @Kris Because there might be more than two different caps. Please see the other comment.

Comment: @choster Thanks for the help clarifying my question. In fact - there is a third option too. It's the metal cap that needs to be leveraged and lifted by a bottle opener. I doubt it's called a lift-off... Or is it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I just realized what you meant by *screw cap* I thought it was a synonym to *twist-off* because **screwing** and **twisting** are similar to each other! But The screwiness refers to the screwing out using a device, right? In any case - I see that we're missing the third option: a metal cap that needs to be lifted off using an opener. That's not a lift-off, is it?

Comment: @Konrad: Per my previous comment, I call that a *crown cork* (because I'm older, and English). Most people (WS2, and most Americans) call it a *crown cap*. I never heard *lift-off* used in such contexts - it seems more suitable for *ring-pulls* on Coke cans, or the lids on [sardine cans](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w23N46lIToI)

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten - I hope your teacher meant you can use "What'd" freely in speech, in which case it could mean "What had,", "What did," or "What would" - all down to your pronunciation. In writing it is used to mean "What did". I don't think I have ever seen "What'd" for "What would" or "What had".

Comment: @nxx Nope. It was very clearly specified that (according to her, that is) "*what'd*", as "*I'd*", "*he'd*" etc. were contractions of either "*x had*" or "*x would*" for usage in written, if not academic or formal, writing. It was equally clearly stated (and corrected accordingly during the tests) that "*x did*" was **never** to be contracted that way. I guess one learns new stuff every day...

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten Indeed, "I'd" and "he'd" etc can equally be contracted as "I/he would/had", but never "did", while "what'd", should be "what did" but not "had" or "would" (although, with poetic license, I guess you could get away with "what had", as in "what'd you done?", although it still sounds strange). And yes, of course, no contractions in formal writing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional bottle cap is simple known as a *[crown cap](http://www.crown-caps.com/)* or *crown cork*, and there was a time when simply saying *bottle cap* indicated a crown cap which invariably required a [church key](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1434/whats-the-origin-of-churchkey-meaning-a-can-or-bottle-opener) or [similar tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_opener) to remove.

But just as the advent of the push-button telephone requires us to specify *rotary phone*, and of the mobile phone to say *land line* or *home phone* instead of just *phone*, the popularity of [*twist-off* bottle caps](http://m5.paperblog.com/i/71/713084/starr-hill-moving-away-from-twist-off-bottle--L-5K1PUy.png) has led the rise of the term ***[pry-off](http://columbianewsservice.com/2012/02/the-great-twist-offpry-off-debate/)*** or *pry caps* among beer enthusiasts. Googling around you will find it in widespread use on homebrew sites, and it used [by at](http://www.boulevard.com/removing-the-twist-from-our-bottles/) least [a few](http://www.summitbrewing.com/media-resources/summit-brewing-company-makes-the-switch-to-pry-off-bottle-caps) brewers [as well](http://www.anchorbrewing.com/blog/ask-bob-brewer-why-do-craft-breweries-not-use-twist-off-bottle-caps/). By synechdoche, a *twist-off* can refer to a bottle capped with a twist-off cap, or the sort of brew sold in such bottles.

Twist-off bottle caps are easier to open, but more complicated to manufacture and, it is claimed, an inferior seal. They were therefore adopted primarily for mass market, mass consumption brews— the Coca-Colas and Heinekens and Budweisers of the world. Smaller bottlers would not have found the need to invest in the machinery for twist-off caps, and this has even become a point of differentiation among craft brewers.

In North America, I've almost never heard the term *screw cap* or *screw top* applied to crown cap bottles like beer bottles; for beverages they refer mainly to the type of [metal cap found on Australian wines](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aWine_bottle_screwcap.JPG), with similar mass market associations.

Comment: Hello. Can you tell me if I want to give direction to someone to twist wine cork into bottle to close it, can I say "You need to twist-in that cork" or "You need to twist-on that cork"? How would this be opposite with twisting wine cork off the bottle if I want someone to open it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The modern bottle cap, invented in 1890, was originally known as a 'crown cap'. The ones we use today, it would appear, are the 'pilfer-proof' version invented in 1936. But if I needed to refer to that type of cap, as opposed to a twist-cap,or some other variety, I think I would call it a 'standard crown cap'. I am not clear what is meant by a 'twist-cap', other than those that are replacing corks on wine bottles. Any ale I drink from  a bottle is sealed with a standard crown cap.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK twist-off is very rare, but as an alternative we have pop-off caps or pop caps - these are crown caps as mentioned by WS2, but no-one ever uses that terminology in the UK.

Comment: The important thing is what the beer tastes like.